# Normal Distribution while finding sigma

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, order-statistics

I was reading some things about normal distribution and saw this problem in a text a couple days ago. I know it might be a little advanced for me at the moment, but I was wanted to know if someone can help me to see how you would solve this problem.

> Assume that the lifetime in hours of a computer chip is normally distributed with mean $5000$ hours. If a producer wants at least $80%$ of the chips to have lifetimes exceeding $4200$ hours, what is the largest value the standard deviation $\sigma$ can have?

I know from reading that we can find the cutoff value of $\sigma_c$ which corresponds to exactly $80%$ having lifetimes exceeding $4200$ hours.

Here is how I did the part of the problem:

We find that $0.80*4200=3360$

$Z=X-\mu/\sigma$

$P(X\geq 4200.5)$ $=$ $4200.5-5000/\sigma$

Is it ok if someone can help me solve this type of problem? It looks like something good to know for the future.

Comment: The problem seems under-specified. How many chips is the person using? Also, there is no way to have **certainty** that at least $80$ chips (out of say $150$) will live that long. The best we can do is to determine a variance such  that with probability (for example) $0.95$ at least $80$ chips will live that long.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, this is just a problem that I was reading. I wanted to know the largest value the standard deviation $\sigma$ can have. I think we can find the largest variance first. The answer says 950.1 hours. I was curious to see how the author got that.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I know there is a formula that I saw $z_1=p_1-p/\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$. Does it apply here?

Comment: The formula you are quoting is for estimating a proportion. It has no real connection to your problem. As I mentioned earlier, the question you raised is under-specified.